# using headless chrome as a general command line web utility- I wrote my own ( "Chromate ") but curious what exists

Tags: selenium, puppeteer, wget, google-chrome-headless

I wrote a bibtex citation discovery tool ( " TooBib ", [outdated doc draft](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/350608962_toobib)
) that required Chrome emulation for some sites. As wget does not support
some SSL schemes, headless chrome seemed like a good choice but I did not
want to get and learn a bunch of things like Selenium or nodejs etc( I think I
had an issue installing Puppeteer ) . It turned out to be
easy to invoke if from system() calls via c++ and talk directly to the debug
port with websockets. As it can execute arbitrary javascript code, it is now
quite flexible although maybe more cumbersome than things like wget.
Does something like this already exist in simple form?
Thanks.

Comment: You can do: `chrome --headless --enable-logging --dump-dom https://www.google.com/`

Comment: That does not work on pdf etc AFAICT. But short javascript does although there isa problem with "content disposition"

Comment: There's a print to pdf option I believe. Otherwise, you know, learn javascript and customize it to your needs I guess.

Comment: Maybe I should just restate the question, " what is the easiest way to make headless chrome act kind of like wget?" The command line options don't seem to make downloading an arbitrary file easy and to add javascript it looks like most people use Selenium or Puppeeteer or similar. I guess these are not difficult to install for most systems but is there anything simpler? The c++ code to interact directly with the debgging port is pretty easy but maybe someone can do it all in bash with a websocket utility.